# Interstitial iAd gives breakpoint on closing add

Tags: xcode, swift

I wrote code so that an interstitial ad would pop up. The add pop ups fine, but when I try to close it there is a breakpoint in the presentInterlude function "if interstitial.loaded". Anyone have any idea why this is happening?
I can't seem to figure it out.

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

This is the error it gives.

```
var interstitial:ADInterstitialAd!
var closeButton:UIButton!
var placeHolderView:UIView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //loadInterstitialAd()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: ("runAd:"),    name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)


}

//iAD interstitial
func runAd(notification:NSNotification){
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("dislayiAdInterstitial"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    cycleInterstitial()
}

func cycleInterstitial(){

    // Clean up the old interstitial...
    //  interstitial.delegate = nil;
    // and create a new interstitial. We set the delegate so that we can be notified of when
    interstitial = ADInterstitialAd()
    interstitial.delegate = self;
}

func presentInterlude(){
    // If the interstitial managed to load, then we'll present it now.
    if (interstitial!.loaded) {

        placeHolderView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
        self.view.addSubview(placeHolderView)

        closeButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 270, y:  25, width: 25, height: 25))
        closeButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "error"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        closeButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("close"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
        self.view.addSubview(closeButton)


        interstitial.presentInView(placeHolderView)
    }
}

// iAd Delegate Mehtods

// When this method is invoked, the application should remove the view from the screen and tear it down.
// The content will be unloaded shortly after this method is called and no new content will be loaded in that view.
// This may occur either when the user dismisses the interstitial view via the dismiss button or
// if the content in the view has expired.

func interstitialAdDidUnload(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!){
    placeHolderView.removeFromSuperview()
    closeButton.removeFromSuperview()
    interstitial = nil

    cycleInterstitial()
}


func interstitialAdActionDidFinish(_interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!){
    placeHolderView.removeFromSuperview()
    closeButton.removeFromSuperview()
    interstitial = nil

    println("called just before dismissing - action finished")

}

// This method will be invoked when an error has occurred attempting to get advertisement content.
// The ADError enum lists the possible error codes.
func interstitialAd(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!,
    didFailWithError error: NSError!){
        cycleInterstitial()
}


//Load iAd interstitial
func dislayiAdInterstitial() {
    //iAd interstitial
    presentInterlude()
}


func close() {
    placeHolderView.removeFromSuperview()
    closeButton.removeFromSuperview()
    interstitial = nil

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is, that at the moment where you call the method `cycleInterstitial`. your `interstitial` isn't initialized. You need to change the order of the calls from:

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("dislayiAdInterstitial"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
cycleInterstitial()
```

To:

```
cycleInterstitial()
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("dislayiAdInterstitial"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

That way, your `ADInterstitialAd` is initialized and can be used in your `presentInterlude` method.

Also I would unwrap the `interlude` object to handle the possibility, that the interlude is `nil`. So unwrap it by using `if let`. Also you can directly test it on the same line of code if the unwrapped value is loaded.

So replace that:

```
if (interstitial!.loaded) {
```

With that:

```
if let unwrappedInterstitial = interstitial where unwrappedInterstitial.loaded{
```

Also you need to use the unwrappedInterstitial in your if-cause, instead of interstitial.

So that line of code basically means that: 
1. Check if the interstitial exists and isn't `nil`, if it's not `nil` check the unwrapped object, if the unwrapped object is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the input Christian! I appreciate it a lot. I changed the code but it is still giving the same error unfortunately.. Do you by any chance know another way to implement interstitials? Have been looking all over the place and I feel this method is not the cleanest..

Comment: Have you unwrapped the interstitial like i showed in my answer?

Comment: Not yet, having a hard time to figure out where to place it exactly, could you show it by using my code how you would write it exactly?

Comment: I think your problem is, that you set the object to nil in the close function. and you only initialize the object ones, but you reshow it every 0.1 seconds.

Comment: I set it to 10 seconds and it is still giving the same error I tried setting it longer and it definitely showed that the error happens when it tries to repeat the interstitial show. I tried implementing your code and it gives me the following error "Braced block of statements is an unused closure"..